Migration to quorum queues. Auto-deleted quorum queues
In our system architecture, applications retrieve their initial state independently from real-time events. To achieve this, we utilize RabbitMQ's exclusive auto-delete classic queues with server-generated names, which perfectly meet our requirements.
However, RabbitMQ is promoting a shift towards quorum queues, which unfortunately do not support these features.
We can devise a workaround for generating unique queue names and use the single-active-consumer property to simulate an exclusive queue. Yet, the challenge remains in creating an auto-deleted queue that will be removed once the host connection is closed.
Any assistance or insights on this matter would be greatly appreciated.
To be honest even RabbitMQ devs admit that in such case it is better to use classic queues but starting from 3.13 management console displays a banner that warns on using deprecated features and it was clearly communicated that there will be no classic queues starting from the next major release.

you might want to set a queue ttl? x-expires

Expiry time can be set for a given queue by setting the x-expires
argument to queue.declare, or by setting the expires policy. This
controls for how long a queue can be unused before it is automatically
deleted. Unused means the queue has no consumers, the queue has not
been recently redeclared (redeclaring renews the lease), and basic.get
has not been invoked for a duration of at least the expiration period.
This can be used, for example, for RPC-style reply queues, where many
queues can be created which may never be drained.

